# I want to prove that some functions are not one-to-one. Are both notations correct?

Tags: solution-verification

I want to prove that some functions are not one-to-one.

Are both these proofs written correct?

1. $\exists\,x_1=1,\,x_2=-1\;[1\neq -1 \wedge f(1)=f(-1)]$
2. $\exists\,x_1=1,\,x_2=-1\;[x_1\neq x_2 \wedge f(x_1)=f(x_2)]$

Comment: The use of notation has variations. They could be ok or not, depending on the context. Both look understandable, and expressing the existence of one example proving that a function is not one-to-one, from the usual ways the symbols in them are commonly used.

Comment: I haven't seen either of these notations, but the notation is clear. So it depends really on the notation of your class/book/professor.

Comment: I would normally write $f(1)=f(-1)$ and $1\neq -1,$ so $f$ is not one-to-one. Basically, $\exists$ is a formal symbol, and your notation is not a formal usage of that symbol.

Comment: Correct? Yes. Clear? Maybe not.

Comment: Context? Missing. I suppose $f\colon \Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$ is a function. Or is the domain different? Over $\Bbb F_2$, say, $1=-1$ is true.

Comment: I think it’d be better to just write in normal sentences.

Comment: Thank all, I have to use that notation. My teacher use first one but I was curious will she give me points for the second one i used on the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen the notation $\exists_{x_1=1}$.  It is clear what you mean, but unless you are following the notation of your instructor it would be best to avoid this.

I would personally suggest just saying

> Since $f(-1) = f(1)$ we can see that $f$ is not one-to-one.

If you wanted to be **extremely** formal you could say something like:

> A function $f:X \to Y$is said to be **one to one** if
> $$\forall x_1 \in X \forall x_2 \in X f(x_1) = f(x_2) \implies x_1 = x_2$$
> We want to show that our particular $f$ is not one-to-one.  Assume $f$ is one-to-one.  Notice that $f(-1) = f(1)$ for our particular $f$.  So if $f$ were one-to-one we would have that $-1=1$, which is absurd.  Thus $f$ is not one-to-one.

Comment: Yup. Using both "there exists" and exhibiting a specific value is redundant, kinda confusing, and makes it harder for your readers to understand your intention. If your prof requires it, then I guess you have to use it, but I encourage you to drop it as soon as you get out of that class